# VNC For Ubuntu16.04 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, vnc, google

I have setup Ubuntu16.04 LTS as VM on the Google compute engine platform. I am trying to install a vnc on this platform.

I installed the gnome desktop using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop metacity nautilus
```

This is how my xstartup file looks like:

```
    #!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#gnome-session -session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

After restarting the VNCserver, I still get a grey backdrop for the desktop. In the foreground, there is a window that displays the home directory with a white background. The application and places drop down menus are visible..

I suspect i might have not installed the gnome desktop correctly. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Should i be posting this query on some other SO site?